# Не переведена страница "Manifesto of Stack Overflow in Russian"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Не переведена как [сама страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), так и ссылка на нее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Хмм, впервые вижу этот манифест. А кто его сочинял?

Comment: @NickVolynkin там в конце страницы ссылочка есть :)

Comment: сам текст легко перевести, но содержимое (я думаю) можно существенно сильнее сделать -- существуют более весомые аргументы, почему имеет смысл иметь SO на других языках, даже если мы начнём с позиции (которую я разделяю) что _профессиональный_ программист обязан *эффективно* общаться на английском, к примеру, 1- не только профессиональные программисты программируют (другие профессии, дети, хобби) 2- у локализированного SO может быть своё сообщество со своей культурой (что может иметь значение для эффективной коммуникации, для мотивации участия в проекте). 3- даже размер может иметь значение

Comment: у других людей могут свои пункты быть ещё. На 2-ой пункт я рассчитывал в 2015 году, к сожалению, из-за токсичный мета-дискуссий последнее время, он скорее минусом является. Про 3-ий: популярные метки на английском SO могут слишком много однотипных вопросов публиковать (и быстро усталость вызывать из-за этого). Исследования говорят, что может быть выгодно быть относительно большой рыбой в маленьком аквариуме.